# What is the best way to compare two different enums?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm thinking what is the best way to compare values from two different enums.

Example:

```
public enum ExampleEnumA
{
    ExampleValue
}

public enum ExampleEnumB
{
    ExampleValue
}

 if (ExampleEnumA.ExampleValue.ToString() == ExampleEnumB.ExampleValue.ToString())
 {

 }
```

Comparing strings work, but I know that it's not the most efficient and eligent way. How it can be done better?

**EDIT:**

Maybe it's a design flaw, but it's problem from a real project, not my incorrect understanding of enums. This is how it looks like and there was no time to refactor whole approach.

```
public interface IProvider
{
    Enum SectionType { get; }
}

public class FirstProvider : IProvider
{
    public Enum SectionType
    {
        get { return ExampleEnumA.ExampleValue; }
    }
}

public class SecondProvider : IProvider
{
    public Enum SectionType
    {
        get { return ExampleEnumB.ExampleValue; }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public void TmpMethod(Enum sectionType)
    {
        var provider = GetFromIoC...

        if (provider.SectionType == sectionType)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the enum 'labels' have the same (int) values for each seperate enum?

Comment: What do you expect, the only difference in enums are the labels since they are based on int*. So comparing them by anything else is impossible since their labels give them semantic meaning and nothing else. Also how can you say that apple_pie is the same as apfel_kuchen ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? I'm unable to find a good example where comparing 2 different enums is semantically correct.

Comment: You need to explain what your comparison criteria are. If "equal" means "having the same enum member name", then your approach is fine. If you want to compare the underlying numeric value, you can compare on that. _"most efficient and elegant"_ isn't really quantifyable and I'm sure this won't pose a concrete efficiency problem as using your code you can still compare millions of enums a second.

Comment: enums are constant in runtime. so comparing them like this doesnt really make sense to me. except if they were flagged. that make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enumerations are like an abstraction layer on top a regular class of integer-based constants.

That abstraction includes evaluating `false` even if two enumeraiton values are the same integer but belong to different enumeration types.

What's the best way of comparing two different enumeration types with same underlying value? I would answer that **it should be a design flaw if you need to perform this evaluation**.

For example, let's say we've implemented these enumerations:

```
public enum States
{
    Open = 1, 
    Closed
}

public enum SpecialFolders 
{
     ProgramFiles86 = 1,
     ProgramFiles64
}
```

Would make sense something like `States.Open == SpecialFolders.ProgramFiles86`? Potentially, they seem to be equal (they won't) because both enumeration values have an underlying value of `1`, but `1` doesn't mean the same if the enumeration type isn't the same.

It's like saying that...

1. Bread
2. Meat

...is the same as:

1. Steal *(Bread == Steal????????????)*
2. Wood

### Maybe...

...you can defeat the purpose of typing constants as enumerations casting them to `int`:

```
if ((int)ExampleEnumA.ExampleValue == (int)ExampleEnumB.ExampleValue)
{

}
```

...if the underlying type is `int`. It could also be `long`:

```
public enum SomeEnum : long 
{
}
```

...and you would need to cast left and right part of your evaluation to `long`, and so on.

Anyway, I insist that you shouldn0t go this way. Maybe you should use a regular class of constants instead and you'll avoid 2 casts per evaluation:

```
public static class States
{
     public const int Open = 1;
     public const int Closed = 2;
}

public static class Materials
{
    public const int Steel = 1;
    public const int Wood = 1;
}

// true! but not that true... I can't understand why these constants equal...
if(States.Open == Materials.Wood)
{
}
```

BTW, I still consider this a *design flaw* and you should avoid not using enumerations to workaround a bad design decision.

Comment: Your example seems to compare apples with oranges. But there are cases where you need to compare slightly different apples which does not really constitute as design flaw.  Consider this example: Two objects each with their own internal enums.  The order of some values might differ and they might have additional values. ex: ( `enum{ whiteApple, redApple}`  vs.  `enum{ redApple, whiteApple, greenApple}`). I still need a way to get the common denominator between these two, coming from outside these encapsulating objects. Note: These two objects are in different libraries.

Comment: The underlying concept of enum is to represent them as integers or compatible types and if you have arrived at a design where in you have to compare between two enums then it seriously is a design flaw.

Comment: [Consider this case](https://gyazo.com/88efbf60b0ba1d73245c69a552bc3ee5.png). Do you still think it is a design flaw to compare `enum PieceType  {BLACK, WHITE, NONE}` to `enum PlayerTyper {BLACK, WHITE}`?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Probably. We should ask ourselves why there're two `enum` in that case. It would make sense that there could just be `PieceType` and it could be re-used for both piece and player things...